# Using tags such as bold or italic in slim?

Tags: html, ruby, slim-lang

Let's say I have this code in HTML:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum, <b>volutpat</b>. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.</p>
```

How would I convert that to slim? Throughout all of [Slim's documentation](http://slim-lang.com/), it never once mentions bold, italic, or any other inline elements. I tried this:

```
p Lorem ipsum, b volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
```

As expected it just added a 'b' to the text. I also tried using tubes:

```
p Lorem ipsum, 
  | b volutpat.
  | Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
```

This gave me the exact same result, plus. If anyone could help, I'd greatly appreciate it! Here is just a few trials that I was trying to work out: http://codepen.io/spikeyty/pen/wruIs

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's sometimes not worth following every rule. Use this and you are fine.

```
p Lorem ipsum, <b>volutpat</b>. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
```

You can also use Markdown directly in Slim if a lot of bolds and italics appear in your text, for example:

```
p Normal slim syntax.
markdown:
  Lorem Markdownum, **volutpat**. Ut wisi *enim* ad minim `veniam`.
```

Comment: Great work! Thanks for the multiple solutions. I made this the "Correct Answer".

Answer (score 17):

```
p
 |Lorem ipsum, 
 b volutpat. 
 |Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
```

This gets rendered as "Lorem ipsum, **volutpat**. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam." (see your updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/spikeyty/pen/wruIs)).

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slim-template/h8fYkG5lj9k

Answer (score 5):

Those tags are considered deprecated, please consider using their newer versions.

`<b>` has been replaced with `<strong>`

`<i>` has been replaced with `<em>`

It shoud be something like

```
p
  | Lorem ipsum,
  strong volutpat.
  | Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zheCt)

Comment: Thanks for the demo, that worked. However <b> <i> <strong> AND <em> are in HTML5. They each have different meaning. The answer here explains it fairly well. http://bit.ly/JvajYX Am I wrong?

Comment: This is incorrect; these tags are not deprecated: http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/